# PHP Symfony 4 Cannot Export Data in CSV File

Tags: php, export-to-csv, symfony4

My following code is not returning any error, however, instead of it returns a CSV file, it returns data string in an HTML page.  I don't know what I missed in my symfony settings.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $sql = "select name, id from table";
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $source = new PDOStatementSourceIterator($stmt);

    $format='csv';
    $export_to='php://output';
    $exporterWriter='\Exporter\Writer\\'.ucfirst($format).'Writer';
    $writer = new $exporterWriter($export_to);

    Handler::create($source, $writer)->export();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="data.csv"');

    return $response;
```

Comment: try adding `$response->headers->set('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');`

Comment: Symfony controllers require the action to return a response that contains data. You need to change `$export_to = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), uniqid());` to create a temporary physical file and use `return  $this->file($export_to, 'data.csv', ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);` See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files or https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#streaming-file-responses for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I updated the code as you suggested it could return a file but there is no content (empty file).